# Python cryptography: create a certificate signed by an existing CA, and export

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

I am creating a CA like so:

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -out ca.cert
```

This gives me two PEM files.

I then call this function where `cert_authority` and `private_key` are the strings of the data generated above.

```
def create_cert(cert_authority, private_key):
    one_day = datetime.timedelta(1, 0, 0)
    # Use our private key to generate a public key
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        private_key.encode("ascii"), password=None, backend=default_backend()
    )
    public_key = private_key.public_key()

    ca = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(
        cert_authority.encode("ascii"), default_backend()
    )

    builder = x509.CertificateBuilder()
    builder = builder.subject_name(
        x509.Name([x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u"cryptography.io")])
    )
    builder = builder.issuer_name(ca.issuer)
    builder = builder.not_valid_before(datetime.datetime.today() - one_day)
    builder = builder.not_valid_after(datetime.datetime.today() + (one_day * 30))
    builder = builder.serial_number(x509.random_serial_number())
    builder = builder.public_key(public_key)

    cert = builder.sign(
        private_key=private_key, algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), backend=default_backend()
    )

    print(cert.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM))
```

This then generates what appears to be a cert, however on copying and pasting the data to a file (and wrapping by 64 lines and using Unix newlines as per http://srdevspot.blogspot.com/2011/08/openssl-error0906d064pem.html) I get this error when trying to validate:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt -untrusted phone.crt
unable to load certificates
```

Hoping I am missing something simple as I'm new to all this!

Finally I'll note that I'm open to using another crypto library if cryptography isn't the best.

EDIT:

Now using this per Paul's very helpful response:

```
def create_cert(cert_authority, private_key):
    one_day = datetime.timedelta(1, 0, 0)
    # Use our private key to generate a public key
    root_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        private_key.encode("ascii"), password=None, backend=default_backend()
    )

    root_cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(
        cert_authority.encode("ascii"), default_backend()
    )

    # Now we want to generate a cert from that root
    cert_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
        public_exponent=65537, key_size=2048, backend=default_backend()
    )
    new_subject = x509.Name(
        [
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"Texas"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, u"Austin"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"New Org Name!"),
        ]
    )
    cert = (
        x509.CertificateBuilder()
        .subject_name(new_subject)
        .issuer_name(root_cert.issuer)
        .public_key(cert_key.public_key())
        .serial_number(x509.random_serial_number())
        .not_valid_before(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        .not_valid_after(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=30))
        .add_extension(
            x509.SubjectAlternativeName([x509.DNSName(u"somedomain.com")]),
            critical=False,
        )
        .sign(root_key, hashes.SHA256(), default_backend())
    )

    # Dump to scratch
    with open("scratch/phone_cert.pem", "wb") as f:
        f.write(cert.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM))

    # Return PEM
    cert_pem = cert.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM)

    cert_key_pem = cert_key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption(),
    )

    return cert_pem, cert_key_pem
```

Would that be the correct way to both save a file and return the created cert and private key as PEM strings?

I am also finding that when I attempt to verify the created cert against the saved PEM with `openssl verify -verbose -CAfile ca.crt -untrusted phone_cert.pem` the command never returns -- probably a separate issue but would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two issues that I see here. First, you're creating another self-signed certificate so the certificate you've generated is not signed by the CA, it is itself a CA. To correct this you **sign** with the private key of your CA (e.g. `private_key` in your example), but you need to create a **new** private key associated with the new certificate and embed the public key of that in the cert.

```
certificate_private_key = <generate an ec or rsa key here>
certificate_public_key = certificate_private_key.public_key()
```

Then do

```
builder = builder.public_key(certificate_public_key)
```

You also have an issue with your output because you're trying to copy and paste things out of a print statement. The output of `cert.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM)` will be a valid X509 certificate with delimiters and proper PEM line lengths, so write it directly to a file:

```
with open("cert.crt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(cert.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM))
```

The result can be parsed with `openssl x509 -noout -text -in cert.crt`

Here is a complete example utilizing `cryptography` to create a self-signed root CA and sign a certificate using that CA.

```
import datetime

from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa


root_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)
subject = issuer = x509.Name([
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"Texas"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, u"Austin"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"My Company"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u"My CA"),
])
root_cert = x509.CertificateBuilder().subject_name(
    subject
).issuer_name(
    issuer
).public_key(
    root_key.public_key()
).serial_number(
    x509.random_serial_number()
).not_valid_before(
    datetime.datetime.utcnow()
).not_valid_after(
    datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=3650)
).sign(root_key, hashes.SHA256(), default_backend())

# Now we want to generate a cert from that root
cert_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)
new_subject = x509.Name([
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"Texas"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, u"Austin"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"New Org Name!"),
])
cert = x509.CertificateBuilder().subject_name(
    new_subject
).issuer_name(
    root_cert.issuer
).public_key(
    cert_key.public_key()
).serial_number(
    x509.random_serial_number()
).not_valid_before(
    datetime.datetime.utcnow()
).not_valid_after(
datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
).add_extension(
    x509.SubjectAlternativeName([x509.DNSName(u"somedomain.com")]),
    critical=False,
).sign(root_key, hashes.SHA256(), default_backend())
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- super helpful.

I put some revised code in the OP, is that looking more correct?

Comment: Yep, that looks much better. SubjectKeyIdentifier/IssuerKeyIdentifiers can also be embedded here to make chain building easier, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 10):

I have to post an answer since I'm new and can't comment yet

I heavily relied on Pauls answer for my own implementation, that was very informative and helpful. But I had to add one more extension on the CA certificate in order to get `openssl verify -verbose -CAfile ca.crt client.crt` to work properly.

Adding `.add_extension(x509.BasicConstraints(ca=True, path_length=None), critical=True)` to the root CertificateBuilder did the trick.

```py
ca_crt = x509.CertificateBuilder() \
    .subject_name(subject) \
    .issuer_name(issuer) \
    .public_key(ca_key.public_key()) \
    .serial_number(x509.random_serial_number()) \
    .not_valid_before(datetime.datetime.today() - one_day) \
    .not_valid_after(datetime.datetime.today() + (one_day * 365)) \
    .add_extension(x509.BasicConstraints(ca=True, path_length=None), critical=True) \
    .sign(ca_key, hashes.SHA256(), default_backend())
```

Did everything else just like Paul.

Comment: Thanks! I came here to write same thing. Spend some time debugging it. Without `add_extension()` I was getting "error 79 at 1 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate" and "verification failed". Let this text be here for search engines.